# Language code prepended twice when using url-reverse template filter and i18n urls with localeurl

Tags: python, django, django-localeurl

Django 1.5, using the app

```
localeurl
```

With urlpattern like so :

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^user/login/?$','django.contrib.auth.views.login',\
          {'template_name':'user/login.html'}),
)
```

and in the template, this

```
{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}
```

prepends the language code twice . It outputs "en/en/user/login" .

Does anybody have an idea how to get rid of the double language code, or where this might come from ?

Comment: "Normally" you shouldnt need to use an additional app with Django 1.5 to use localized url-patterns. Maybe Django and the localeurl both add a prefix.

Comment: @Jingo, thank you, was unaware of that . However, without "localeurl", no language code at all is added to the url.

Comment: Make sure you load the appropriate middlewares. Cant remember them but its very well documented in the django online help/documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was to add the **same** url-patterns with both

`urlpatterns += patterns( ... )` and

`urlpatterns += i18n_patterns( ... )`

That caused said error.
It works when the patterns are added only through `i18n_patterns`

Also, "localeurl" is not necessary (thanks @Jingo)